# Можно ли считать "глядя" супплетивным деепричастием от "смотреть"?

Tags: глаголы, словоупотребление

Вопрос может показаться странным, но вот его логика. В современном русском практически не употребляют *смотря* именно как деепричастие — оно прочно стало частью союзов *смотря как*, *смотря где* и т.д. С другой стороны, *глядя* постоянно встречается там, где в любой другой форме говорящий, скорее всего, употребил бы *смотреть*, а не стилистически маркированное *глядеть*.

Эта маркированность в случае *глядя* не воспринимается, и мне кажется, что мысленная операция, приводящая к употреблению *глядя* — это в большинстве случаев постановка глагола *смотреть* в форму деепричастия, примерно так же, как мы неосознанно переключаемся между *класть* и *положить*. Но видовая пара — это все-таки два разных глагола. А тут, если перефразировать подавляющее большинство фраз с *глядя* (через "когда", "пока" и т. п.), естественными будут изъявительные формы глагола *смотреть*, а не *глядеть*.

Дает ли это основания утверждать, что *глядя*, помимо "своего собственного" глагола, употребляется еще и как супплетивное деепричастие от *смотреть*, или это все-таки следует считать заменой глагола как такового?

Comment: Смотря тоже встречается как деепричастие. "Смотря на проезжающий поезд я думал...". Глядя почаще встречается, ну и что?

Comment: @Anixx ruscorpora shows that "смотря" is four times as rare as "глядя" (вчетверо реже), if the preceding for both is not "не" (otherwise there are a lot of wrong-written "несмотря на") whereas all the forms of "смотреть" are three times as frequent as "глядеть" (втрое чаще). So the question seems to make sense, although for now answer is still negative.

Answer (score 8):

Нет, всё-таки это не даёт основание утверждать, что "глядя" есть супплетивное деепричастие от "смотреть". Равно как "одолеем" не является формой будущего времени глагола "победить" только лишь на том основании, что в современном русском языке де-факто никто не говорит "побежду".

Кроме того, как указали в комментариях, форма "смотря" употребляется хоть и реже, но не настолько редко, чтобы мы могли говорить о том, что она исчезла.

Answer (score 5):

Глядеть и смотреть - это не синонимы и, тем более, не супплетивы, они имеют разное значение. Глядеть означает направить взгляд в сторону чего либо. Смотреть означает направить свое внимание на что-либо. Например, глядя в окно, я смотрел на дорогу. Это же относится и к деепричастиям, образованным от этих глаголов.

Comment: "Глядя в окно, я смотрел..." — разве так кто-нибудь говорит? Гуглом (на разные местоимения) находится только любительская проза спорных достоинств, да и той совсем чуть-чуть.

Comment: Я привел эту конструкцию исключительно для того, чтобы показать семантическую разницу между двумя глаголами. Хотя согласен, что с литературной точки зрения, звучит она несколько коряво. )

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что у глаголов "глядеть" и "смотреть" есть общее значение, но каждый из них обладает еще и другими значениями. Например, можно сказать "смотреть кино", но нельзя "глядеть кино". 
"Я часто, смотря кино, отмечаю про себя несоответствия между характерами персонажей и их поведением."

С другой стороны, можно сказать "дерево (луч солнца) глядит в окошко", но нельзя - "дерево смотрит в окошко". Наверняка есть пример с деепричастием у какого-нибудь Пастернака, там у него постоянно намокшие воробушком сиреневые ветви куда-нибудь глядят.

Для супплетивов, насколько я понимаю, необходима идентичность лексических значений, они могут отличаться только грамматически. В случае с "глядеть" и "смотреть" есть разница в лексическом значении. Значит, не получается считать деепричастие "глядя" супплетивной формой глагола "смотреть". Хотя, конечно, идея увлекательная.